# CrmServiceClient: how can I specify a custom oauth2 Authorization Endpoint

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I'm using this piece of code to connect to Dynamics 9.1 OnPremise. But I don't understand how can I specify a custom oauth2 Authorization Endpoint ?

```
string connectionString = "AuthType=Certificate; url=http://ifd-server; Thumbprint=021a1wa210b824dcbe38153890e5a110001ea9db; ClientId=d3157c5d-92c8-ed11-aac4-001012397054; SkipDiscovery=true; RequireNewInstance=true";

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | 
SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
CrmServiceClient crmServiceClient = new 
CrmServiceClient(connectionString); //Connecting to the D-365 CDS instance
```